Is it safe to copy around PostgreSQL bin dir?
An existing old Windows (currently migrated on a Windows 10) environment uses PostgreSQL 9.6 and I use some of the tools (psql.exe and pg_dump.exe) from the bin dir to do backup/restore operations.
This binaries are capable to point to a different host so you can operate remote PostgreSQL instances but they don't come on any "client like" installation or bundle, I need to install a whole PostgreSQL instance on a different PC If I want to have them there even though I won't use the installed instance.
Is it safe to just copy around the "bin" dir from an existing installation into another PC to use them?
PS: I'm aware I may need some C++ redist, that's OK and under control

Yes, that is safe if you do it right. But don't forget to copy the shared libraries (DLL) that the executables require, as well as other files, like message files.
Usually, you shouldn't bother. If your installation packages don't offer an option not to install the server, install the server as well. The PostgreSQL binaries are fairly small and won't fill your disk.

I got to that point of bring the same dir dlls idea, but how about ../lib ones?

Also about "dont bother", if I do that on a client computer to allow a custom tool to do an administration of one of it's servers, looks like overkill to me

As a counterpoint: manually copying DLLs and other files might also be argued to be an overkill. This depends on one's perspective (I'm not saying don't do it, I just want you to have a fuller picture)

About the DLLs in lib: most of them are server libraries, but for example libpq.dll (the client shared library) is essential (Or is that in bin on Windows? Since I don't have any Windows, I'm not certain). Concerning overkill: on my Linux system, a full installation of PostgreSQL v16 is 131MB in size. These days, that's not very much.
